# Arriving at the asymptotic $\int \limits_\lambda^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt \sim \frac{e^{-\lambda^2/2}}{\lambda}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, approximation

In the book "The Probabilistic Method", the integral $\int_\lambda^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt$ is said to be "approximately equal" to $\frac{e^{-\lambda^2/2}}{\lambda}$ for large $\lambda$. I assume what is meant is $\int_\lambda^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt \sim \frac{e^{-\lambda^2/2}}{\lambda}$, which can be verified using l'hopital, since the ratio of the derivatives is $\frac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2+1}$, which tends to 1.

However, it is not clear to me how to arrive at the expression $\frac{e^{-\lambda^2/2}}{\lambda}$ from scratch. Is there a method for that?

Comment: Sorry but you lost me: the question asks for a method to reach the result, not for the result itself, but you (rather swiftly) accepted an answer which merely pulls the result from the hat, while another answer exposes one way (amongst several) to prove it (and to remember it, and to extend it, if I may add). Please explain. For example, would you be able using the accepted answer to compute a simple equivalent when $\lambda\to\infty$ of $$\int_\lambda^\infty t^\alpha e^{-t^2/2}dt\ ?$$

Comment: @Did I believe I can derive the expansion noted in Claude Leibovici's answer, thus I accepted it... We just compute the first few terms in the taylor series of the integrand and substitute $\frac1x$ for $x$, and then integrate explicitly. (and getting the taylor series is just computing the derivatives of the integrand, which can be done by hand.)
Did I miss anything?

Comment: Let me repeat: I mentioned that you asked specifically for a *path*, saying that you knew the destination, and that you got a *destination* as answer, which you accepted immediately. This sounds illogical to me, and you do not explain why this would make sense--but of course you can proceed in whichever way you see fit.

Comment: Laplace's method can be used to obtain the asymptotic integral of  $\int_a^b f(t) e^{- \lambda g(t)} dt$.  References on Laplace's method can be found in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method and https://www.math.unl.edu/~scohn1/8423/intasym1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $t=\dfrac u\lambda+\lambda$,

$$\int_\lambda^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-(u/\lambda+\lambda)^2/2}\frac{du}\lambda=\frac{e^{-\lambda^2/2}}\lambda\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2/2\lambda^2}e^{-u}dt.$$

For large $\lambda$, the second factor decreases faster and

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2/2\lambda^2}e^{-u}du\approx\int_0^\infty e^{-u}du.$$

Answer (score 3):

Almost from definition $$I=\int e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ So $$J=\int_\lambda^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\lambda }{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ Now, look [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.12) for the asymptotic expansion for large $\lambda$ to get $$J=e^{-\frac{\lambda ^2}{2}} \left(\frac{1}{\lambda }-\frac{1}{\lambda ^3}+\frac{3}{\lambda ^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{\lambda^7
   }\right)\right)$$

Comment: So more than $\sim$ is true, but rather $J=\frac{e^{-\frac{\lambda ^2}{2}}}{\lambda} + O(\frac{1}{\lambda ^3})$. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome ! I just wanted to give you still better approximations for your curiosity. Cheers.